# How to use mdadm to assemble arrays from crashed windows server

Tags: raid, mdadm, metadata

I got 12 hard disks from completely crashed server, some of them are failing, too. I successfully saved bit copy of all of them, even not always error free.
I found 512MB superblock on each end of disk starting with a word DSREGION. The 512MB of space is not heavily used and from some text fragments one can judge, that the built-in RAID controller was some LSI model.
The question remains: how can I assemble the RAID arrays using mdadm. How can I tell the mdadm where it can read the superblock while the command:

```
# mdadm -E /dev/loopX
```

does not detect superblock, even if DDF is set explicitly:

```
# mdadm -E -e DDF /dev/loopX
```

If there is a hint how to parse the 512MB superblock I can do the parsing manualy and then I can assemble the RAID arrays explicitly using `mdadm -A`.

Or if there is a possibility to tell mdadm where it has to look for the superblock metadata.

J.

P.S. I hoped I can find something useful at [www.snia.org](http://www.snia.org) but did not find any detail.

Comment: @Massimo: Thanks for your opinion. Yes - I do not have a possibility to start the original server. Yes - on one disk there were 15 unreadable sectors. No - there were no backups. But it is not my fault - I got these disks not to primarily backup the data, and give them back to the owner. I got those disks to analyse the data on them, working in lawenforcement. I have very good experience with mdadm - I restored most of data from 5disk RAID5 from just four disk images. Any **valueble hints** or **helpful comments* are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use mdadm because it cannot handle this job. It has only very limited support for disks that were in hardware RAID arrays, to wit: DDF, and not everyone used that format.

Instead you should be using dmraid to attempt to explore and recover this array. It supports a variety of software, hardware and fake RAID formats. On a recent Linux system it will support:

```
$ dmraid -l
asr     : Adaptec HostRAID ASR (0,1,10)
ddf1    : SNIA DDF1 (0,1,4,5,linear)
hpt37x  : Highpoint HPT37X (S,0,1,10,01)
hpt45x  : Highpoint HPT45X (S,0,1,10)
isw     : Intel Software RAID (0,1,5,01)
jmicron : JMicron ATARAID (S,0,1)
lsi     : LSI Logic MegaRAID (0,1,10)
nvidia  : NVidia RAID (S,0,1,10,5)
pdc     : Promise FastTrack (S,0,1,10)
sil     : Silicon Image(tm) Medley(tm) (0,1,10)
via     : VIA Software RAID (S,0,1,10)
dos     : DOS partitions on SW RAIDs
```

Connect the copies of all the disks you made to a system, turn the computer on, and use `dmraid -r` to see if a set of RAID devices was detected, `dmraid -s <set name>` to get properties of the set, `dmraid -b` to see the status of all block devices that may be part of a set, and if everything looks ok, `dmraid -ay <set name>` will activate the RAID array.

Comment: does dmraid scan image files or only devices? might it be necessary to use loop to make image files appeat as devices?

Comment: @Jasen I have no idea if it will do anything with loop devices. I don't have an easy way to test it either.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: thanks for the hint. I can easy install the dmraid 1.0.0.rc16-8 and I see.

Comment: @Jasen: I am just going to start with `dmraid`, but I suppose id should be better to convert the disk image into a loop device, because the RAID programs deals mostly with block device (consult the `losetup`)